# Create many CAShapeLayers and create unqiue touch events in them

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I want to display lots of stars, and when the user touches inside one of the stars, I can change the color of the star and append the star id to an array.

I have an array of star coordinates = [[coordinates of vertices of star1], [coordinates of vertices of star2], ...., [coordinates of vertices of star60]]

```
//function to create a star UIBezierPath

func StarFromArray(points: [Array<Int>]  ) -> UIBezierPath {
        let starPath = UIBezierPath()
        let point1 = points[0]
        starPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: point1[0], y: point1[1]))
        
        for i in 1...(starPath.count-1) {
            let ar = starPath[i]
            starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ar[0], y: ar[1]))
        }
        starPath.close()
        
        return starPath
    }


//function to create and display every star from my StarArray, I call this in ViewDidLoad

func loadStar() {
        for i in 0...StarArray.size {
            let ar = StarArray[i]

            let starLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let star = StarFromArray(points: ar)
            
            starLayer.path = star.cgPath
            starLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(starLayer)
            
        }
    }
```

The code above displays all my stars, now I need to create a touch event for each of my stars, so that when a star is touched I can append a star ID to an array.

How do I do this?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let point = touch!.location(in: self.view)

        if starLayer.path!.contains(point) {
            print("star touched")
            starLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            
        }
    }
```

This code above is something that I could use if I had one star, but obviously doesn't work if I have many stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send touch events to layers. You need to manage that yourself. I suggest attaching a gesture recognizer to the view that contains these layers, and then adding an array of structs that contains bounding rectangles for each layer, and figuring out which one was tapped that way.

CALayer does have a hitTest method you can use to figure out if a tap does land in a layer, but you have to call it yourself. You could call `hitTest()` on the parent layer and it would tell you which sub-layer (or the parent layer)'s frame the tap landed on.

If you want to detect taps inside irregular shapes like your star example image, you'd have to write that code yourself. (UIBezierPath and CGPath both have `contains()` methods that you can use to interrogate a path to see if a point lies in the interior of the path.)

Comment: thanks, and yes in practice some of my stars will be close together so I want to detect taps inside these stars and not bounding rectangles. In the last function I've written above I have used the contains() method to check if a point lies in the interior. How do I uniqely name each layer (each star) when I create the layers in my for loop? Then once I've done that I would call hitTest() on parent layer and it would return eg 'star10', then I can add this id to my array?

Comment: can I modify the structure of a CAShapeLayer in order to let me give it an id, eg let star1 = CAShapeLayer() then set CAShapeLayer.id = "Star1"? I've modified my last function written above (touchedbegan) to loop through all the self.view.layer.sublayers, which are all of my CAShape layers aka Stars. Then I can change can change the color of that layer's fill color in order to show that the star has been pressed. However I still need to add a way to id that layer in order to add that star to my array, hence my CAShapeLayer structure question. Is looping through all the sublayers inefficient?

Comment: So I've managed to do it- I created my own MyCAShapelayer class that inherits from CAShape layer, and added a var id = 0 to it. Then I set the id when creating the star layer, so I can then print it out when i find the layer when looping through the view's sublayers. However is this a good approach or will it run very slow if I have say 150 stars, and I'm running on a iphone 7?

Comment: I would suggest using `hitTest()` on the parent layer to identify "candidate" layers that might receive the tap. If you find one, then use `contains()` on the view's path to see if the point actually falls inside the shape (`hitTest()` using CGRects will be very fast. The CGPath `contains()` method is likely to be slower.)